# I want to know the order of sorting the list in descending order

Tags: python, list, sorting

a = [1,3,5,2,7]

sorted a = [7,5,3,2,1]

b = [4,2,1,3,0]

I want to make a list like b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `numpy's argsort`

```
np.argsort([1,3,5,2,7])
```

---

```
array([0, 3, 1, 2, 4])
```

Comment: `argsort` looks useful, hadn't seen it before.  But you probably want `np.argsort(a)[::-1]` to reverse the order as desired in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A base python approach:

```
a = [1,3,5,2,7]
b = [i for i,_ in sorted(enumerate(a),key = lambda p: p[1],reverse = True)]
print(b) #[4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Almost character for character matching answers 40s apart.

Comment: @Holloway Python is like that: "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." -- from the Zen of Python.

Answer (score 1):

Pair each element with its index, sort the pairs and then extract the index.

```
>>> a = [1,3,5,2,7]
>>> b = [e[0] for e in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)]
>>> b
[4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> a = [1,3,5,2,7]
>>> b = sorted(range(len(a)), key=lambda i:a[i], reverse=True)
>>> b
[4, 2, 1, 3, 0]
```

Similar to some other answers provided, this one uses a lambda function as the sort key.  This one differs by producing a list of indexes and sorting it directly, rather than pairing each value with an index and stripping out those values at the end.  That makes it simpler.